# Adding values to JFreeChart XYDataset from csv file using opencsv

Tags: java, csv, jfreechart, opencsv

I am trying to read in a .csv file but I am stuck on how once I've read each line on the csv file and how to add it to the XYDataset.

My algorithm is as follows: read in .csv file -> read each line -> add to dataset -> create chart -> output as frame

`data.csv` has 4 columns: `Time`, `X`, `Y`, `Z`

How do I add each point (time,x), (time,y), (time,z) to the dataset?

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame;
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;

import com.opencsv.CSVReader;

public class Test extends ApplicationFrame
{
    XYDataset dataset;
    JFreeChart chart;
    final ChartPanel chartPanel;
    final int chartWidth = 560;
    final int chartHeight = 367;
    CSVReader reader;
    String[] readNextLine;
    XYSeries series;

   public Test(String applicationTitle) throws IOException 
   {
      super(applicationTitle); 
      dataset = createDataset(); 
      chart = createChart(dataset);   
      chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);  
      chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(chartHeight, chartWidth));  
   }

   public XYDataset createDataset() throws NumberFormatException, IOException
   {
       dataset = new XYSeriesCollection(); 
       try
       {
           reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("data.csv")); 
           while((readNextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) 
           {
              if (readNextLine != null)
              {
                  //add values to dataset
              }
           }
     } 
     catch (FileNotFoundException e)
     {
         System.out.println("File not found!");
     }
     return dataset;
   }

 public JFreeChart createChart(XYDataset dataset) throws      NumberFormatException, IOException
 {
    chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
    "Acceleration vs Time",     //chart title 
    "Time",                     //domain axis label
    "Acceleration",             //range axis label
    createDataset(),            //data
    PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,   //the plot orientation
    true,                       //legend
    true,                       //tooltips
    false);                     //urls

return chart;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    final Test demo = new Test("Test XY Line chart");
    demo.pack();
    RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
    demo.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

The first 10 lines of my dataset look like this:

```
time    x   y   z
0.003   -0.13   0.83    0.6
0.009   -0.12   0.83    0.61
0.012   -0.12   0.82    0.6
0.018   -0.13   0.81    0.61
0.021   -0.13   0.8 0.61
0.025   -0.12   0.8 0.61
0.033   -0.12   0.79    0.6
0.034   -0.11   0.79    0.6
0.039   -0.11   0.79    0.58
0.044   -0.11   0.77    0.57
```

Comment: Where exactly are you 'stuck' - processing the line, parsing the values of the line, creating the dataset, adding to the dataset?

Comment: there is no question in your post..

Comment: @copeg I'm unsure on how to proceed. I've read in each line of the .csv file and I want to add each point [(time,x), (time,y), (time,z)] to the dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where your comment is - you need to first go through the elements of `readNextLine` where each element of the `String[]` will contain the value from your file for a given row (assuming your file is correctly formatted as you said).  So - you need to turn these into variables.  You haven't specified what format these are in, or what data type `Time`,`X`, `Y` and `Z` are.

Given that you're looking at an `XY` chart and your axes are labelled `Time` and `acceleration` - I'm going to guess that they're all Floating Point numbers, with `Time` in decimal seconds and the other variables as accelerations in the various axes. NOTE - if this assumption is wrong - you might need to use a different converter such as `Integer.valueOf()`, but the principle is the same.

before your `while` loop, set up the series that you want to add to.  You'll add to them row by row within the while loop

```
final XYSeries seriesX = new XYSeries("X");
final XYSeries seriesY = new XYSeries("Y");
final XYSeries seriesZ = new XYSeries("Z");
```

within the `while` loop where your comment is

```
//add values to dataset
double Time = Double.valueOf(readNextLine[0]);
double X = Double.valueOf(readNextLine[1]);
double Y = Double.valueOf(readNextLine[2]);    
double Z = Double.valueOf(readNextLine[3]);
seriesX.add(Time, X);
seriesY.add(Time, Y);
seriesZ.add(Time, Z);
```

and after the `while` loop add the 3 series to the collection before you return it:

```
dataset.addSeries(seriesX);
dataset.addSeries(seriesY);
dataset.addSeries(seriesZ);
```

***Lastly*** - two comments

1. Your logic is a little weird around dataset creation.  In your constructor, you create the dataset and pass it to `createChart()`.  This is quite standard.  But you then call createDataset() inline within the call to `ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(`, thus rendering the first creation of data pointless and doing it all again.  It will work, but is wasteful and might be masking something else that you're intending the code to do.
2. The `if` check in `createDataset()` is redundant - you're already in a while loop based on a condition which means it will always be true.

   ```
   if (readNextLine != null)
   {
   ```

***EDIT - added full working version to clear confusion in several comments***

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame;
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;

import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;

public class Test extends ApplicationFrame {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    XYSeriesCollection dataset;
    JFreeChart chart;
    final ChartPanel chartPanel;
    final int chartWidth = 560;
    final int chartHeight = 367;
    CSVReader reader;
    String[] readNextLine;
    XYSeries series;

    public Test(String applicationTitle) throws IOException {
        super(applicationTitle);
        dataset = createDataset();
        chart = createChart(dataset);
        chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(chartHeight,
                chartWidth));
        this.add(chartPanel);
    }

    public XYSeriesCollection createDataset() throws NumberFormatException,
            IOException {
        dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
        try {
            reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("res\\data.csv"),'\t');
            // Read the header and chuck it away
            readNextLine = reader.readNext();

            // Set up series
            final XYSeries seriesX = new XYSeries("X");
            final XYSeries seriesY = new XYSeries("Y");
            final XYSeries seriesZ = new XYSeries("Z");

            while ((readNextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                // add values to dataset
                double Time = Double.valueOf(readNextLine[0]);
                double X = Double.valueOf(readNextLine[1]);
                double Y = Double.valueOf(readNextLine[2]);
                double Z = Double.valueOf(readNextLine[3]);
                seriesX.add(Time, X);
                seriesY.add(Time, Y);
                seriesZ.add(Time, Z);
            }

            System.out.println(seriesX.getMaxX() + "; " + seriesX.getMaxY());

            dataset.addSeries(seriesX);
            dataset.addSeries(seriesY);
            dataset.addSeries(seriesZ);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found!");
        }
        return dataset;
    }

    public JFreeChart createChart(XYDataset dataset)
            throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
        chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("Acceleration vs Time", // chart
                                                                        // title
                "Time", // domain axis label
                "Acceleration", // range axis label
                dataset, // data
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, // the plot orientation
                true, // legend
                true, // tooltips
                false); // urls

        return chart;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("In here, to create a Test");
        final Test demo = new Test("Test XY Line chart");
        System.out.println("Created, pakcking");
        demo.pack();
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
        demo.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

#### Output with OP supplied first 10 data points

[image: acceleration graph output of program]

Comment: Thanks, so I've thrown a try-catch block where I'm adding converting the Strings to doubles but I'm still getting NumberFormatExceptions. Any idea as to why?

Comment: Yep, it means (some of) the strings from your file are in a format that can't be parsed to a double. Stab in the dark -does your csv file have header row(s)? If so, unless you deal with them before the loop, the code will try to parse them into doubles and throw that Exception. Post a snippet of your data file e.g. first 10 rows if that doesn't give you enough to sort it yourself

Comment: It does. So I'm guessing I can just ignore the first row and start from the next row down? [Here is the first 10 rows anyway.](http://pastebin.com/Z6ssS85r)

Comment: Yep, just ignore the first. Easiest way is just to put an extra call to readNext before the while loop, which will read the header row, and then do nothing with the result of it. Then you can leave everything else the same.

Comment: Right so I called readNext() but no values have been added to the dataset, instead I get a plain application.

Comment: Just realised that you had forgotten to add `this.add(chartPanel);` in the constructor for `Test`.  Thus - the chart panel was never added to the `ApplicationFrame` that is the component that is actually displayed.  I don't usually use jFreeChart with the Application frame as I have my own swing app I test it in - sorry for missing this.  Full working example now edited in.  Note your pasted data was tab separated, so I've altered mine to work with a tab seperated file -remove that if your real version is comma separated.